# Constraint optimization question with linear function being constrained

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

I have a multivariable function $F(x, y) = a(y^2+x)$ representing the total manufacturing output of some process. $x$ and $y$ are variables representing the quantity of resources of each type input into the process and $a$ is a constant which depends on the machine used.

The idea is that we are using the process $F$ which accepts quantities of two types of resources ($x$ and $y$), of which $y$ is far superior (it contributes exponentially to the number of products produced whereas $x$ contributes linearly).

Now, $x$ is cheaper to procure than $y$. So the total cost of a manufacturing run is given by:

$C = tx + wy$

Where $t$ is the cost per unit of $x$ and $w$ is the cost per unit of $y$.

My goal is to find the ideal combination of $x$ and $y$ to fulfill a customer's order of $P$ products. That is, the cheapest combination of $x$ and $y$ which will yield $P$ as the value of $F(x, y)$.

How can I approach this a problem?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the tip about using Lagrangian multiplier, I now have the following:

$P = ay^2 + ax$ <-- The constraint function

$C = tx + wy$

Let us define the Lagrangian:

$\mathscr{L}(x, y, \lambda)=tx + wy -\lambda(ay^2+ax-P)$

$=tx + wy -a \lambda y^2 -a \lambda x +\lambda P$

We take the partial derivatives and set to zero to get the critical points of the Lagrangian:

$0 = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial x} = t-a \lambda$    $\dagger$

$0 = \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial y} = w-2a \lambda y$   $\ddagger$

And we have our constraint function, with $P$ substituted for the output:

$0 = -ay^2 - ax + P$

So the derivative of the Lagrangian at the critical points is given by:

$\nabla \mathscr{L} = \begin{bmatrix} t-a \lambda \cr w-2a \lambda y \cr -ax - ay^2 + P\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\cr 0 \cr 0 \end{bmatrix}$

From here I am unsure how to interpret this result to find the minimum of $C$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

When I try to work out the values for $x$ and $y$ I run into a problem: using the derivative in $\ddagger$ I can get $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ but because the derivative in $\dagger$ does not have a $x$ term, I don't see how I can get $x$ in terms of $\lambda$. I am sure I am missing something here.

Comment: Lagrange Multiplier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Thanks @erfink, this is a new topic for me. From what I understood, this is a constrained optimization class of problem. Would it be correct to say that the function F(x, y) is actually the constraint and C is the function being constrained?

Comment: Yep. The goal as stated is to minimize the cost C(x,y) subject to the constraint of fulfilling the orders $F(x,y)=P$. Note that this is subtly different than maximizing production $F(x,y)$ subject to a fixed budget $C(x,y)=c$ (which is often the way economists approach similar questions). You might also look into the Cobb-Douglas Function (and similar): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb%E2%80%93Douglas_production_function

Comment: @erfink I have edited the question with the working out for the Lagrange multiplier. I'd really appreciate if you can give the remainder of the solution and explain how to properly interpret the result viz a viz the maximum/minimum values.

Comment: @erfink Are you sure this problem can be solved using the Lagrange multiplier? As the function being constrained is linear? Or am I approaching this wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an equality constrained minimization problem.

You want to minimize $C(x,y) = tx + wy$ given that $F(x,y) = a(y^2+x) = P$ or $G(x,y)=a(y^2+x)-P = 0$, which is the equality constraint.

This type of problem can be solved using Lagrange Multipliers, in which we define a new function $\mathscr{L}(x,y)$, called the Lagrangian.

$$\mathscr{L}(x,y,\lambda) = C(x,y) - \lambda G(x,y)$$

We then minimize this new function. To do so, we must obtain the gradient of the Lagrangian and then calculate the point $P=(x,y,\lambda)$ which makes the gradient be zero.

$$\nabla \mathscr{L} = \begin{bmatrix} t-a \lambda \cr w-2a \lambda y \cr -ax - ay^2 + P\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\cr 0 \cr 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now we solve for $x, y$ and $\lambda$.
From the first term of the gradient we get:

$$\lambda = \frac{t}{a}$$
Substituting this in the second term, we get:

$$y=\frac{w}{2t}$$

Finally we can solve for $x$ with the third entry of the the gradient:

$$x=\frac{P}{a}-\frac{w^2}{4t^2}$$

We now know that the point $P_c=(\frac{P}{a}-\frac{w^2}{4t^2},\frac{w}{2t},\frac{t}{a})$ is a critical point of the Lagrangian. But to tell whether it's a minimum or a maximum, we use the discriminant, which is the determinant of the hessian matrix, defined as:

$$H(x,y, \lambda)=\begin{bmatrix} 
{\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial^2 x}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial x \partial y}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial x \partial \lambda}}
\\ {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial y \partial x}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial^2 y}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial y \partial \lambda}} \\ {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial \lambda \partial x}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial \lambda \partial y}} & {\frac{\partial^2 \mathscr{L}}{\partial^2 \lambda}} \end{bmatrix}$$

Calculating all these derivatives, gives us:

$$H(x,y, \lambda)=\begin{bmatrix} 
{0} & {0} & {-a}
\\ {0} & {-2a\lambda} & {-2ay} \\ {-a} & {-2ay} & {0} \end{bmatrix}$$

The discriminant is then:

$$D(x,y,\lambda)=|H(x,y,\lambda)|$$
$$D(x,y,\lambda)=2a^3\lambda$$

Now, the point we found will definitely be a minimum if the discriminant is greater than zero on it.

$$D(P_c)=2ta^2$$

Since $a^2$ is always positive, it then depends on the value of $t$ whether the point is a minimum. If $t>0$ then the point $P_c$ will be the minimum, if $t<0$ then it will be a maximum, and if $t=0$ or $a=0$ then the hessian test is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So if we introduce a constraint such that t, w, a and P are all non-zero and positive, can we then say with certainty that the point you called Pc is the minimum, without the need for the hessian matrix? In that case, could we then also say that C > 0 for all valid values of x, y?

Comment: Please note I have posted another follow-up question related to the interpretation of the result from this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910038

Comment: Unfortunately after checking with some numbers I find that the result is the maximum value of the function and not the minimum. Are there other possible solutions which would give the minimum?